# RichTextBox Not Showing Formatting Until Text Is Selected

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have programmatically added a RichTextBox control to a form, but I seem to be experiencing a lot of issues when trying to format it.  Please note that I have manually added the control through the GDI but also encounter the same problems.

Basically what is happening is that my control is drawn but uses the same initial background color as the form (even though I have manually specified a different color).  The control also appears empty upon loading of the form, however, I can manually click the mouse the obtain a cursor where text 'should' be appearing.

If I click and drag inside the control, all of my text then appears with all of the formatting I defined.  I have no idea what is causing this, but I have tried to Refesh the form, Refresh the Control, Update the control but nothing works.  I have also tried using `.Text`, `.SelectedText` and `.AppendText`, as well as `.SelectionColor` and `.SelectionBackColor`.

My code is simply this:

```
Dim rtb As RichTextBox = New RichTextBox
rtb.Location = New Point(94, 229)
rtb.Size = New Size(608, 46)
rtb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(38, 38, 38)
rtb.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
rtb.AppendText(_ticket.ticket_lastcomment)
Me.Controls.Add(rtb)
```

Yet it creates a new RichTextBox that is the same color as the form (Color.Control) and empty.  No formatting is applied to the control until I highlight the text manually.

I have never come across this before.

**UPDATE**

After various trial and error and moving code, I have come to find that the piece of code preventing the drawing of the RichTextBox is this:

```
Me.animator = New FormAnimator(Me, FormAnimator.AnimationMethod.Centre, FormAnimator.AnimationDirection.Right, 200)
```

I apply a FormAnimator to the form to give it an effect upon opening.  Removing this piece of code allows the RichTextBox to draw correctly.....strange.

Comment: Does the control change to the right appereance when you move the window around without touching the control itself? If so, you definitely have a redraw problem. You could also try .Invalidate() on the textbox.

Comment: @WeSt No it doesn't. It only updates when I manually highlight the text.  Also, the `.Invalidate` on the textbox doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
rtb.rtf =_ticket.ticket_lastcomment
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late for this answer, but it may help future visitors.
All you have to do, is add first the RichTextBox to the form and then set the text:

```
Me.Controls.Add(rtb)
rtb.AppendText(_ticket.ticket_lastcomment)
```